# How can I stop virtualenv changing my PATH order

Tags: bash, path, virtualenv

My current state is this:

```
>>> virtualenv --version
1.11.6
>>> export PATH=$(getconf PATH)
>>> . ~/.bashrc
>>> echo -e "${PATH//:/\\n}"
/bin
/usr/bin
/home/jozxyqk/bin
/usr/local/cuda/bin
```

But after activating a virtual environment,

```
>>> . env/bin/activate
>>> echo -e "${PATH//:/\\n}"
/home/jozxyqk/somepath/env/bin
/usr/local/cuda/bin
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/usr/lib64/ccache
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/home/jozxyqk/bin
```

Now `/usr/local/cuda/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` and things start using a really old version of `gcc` because there's a symlink in `cuda/bin` (I'm trying to `pip install` stuff that needs gcc). Now in my case I can work around this by removing my symlink, but afaik ordering in `PATH` is pretty important to preserve. Apart from breaking things, allowing the position of `/usr/bin` to change seems like [a bit of a security issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26048).

Is this a bug and is there a workaround or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I'm  guessing `virtualenv` remembers the path you had when you first set it up.

Comment: @tripleee Ooh. Activate just doesn't refresh the path when re-run. Great catch! Don't I feel silly now. `unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH` and re-running activate solves it. I'll accept the answer if you write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtualenv` remembers the path you had when you first set it up.  `unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH` and re-run `activate` to reset it.